# Simulate Material-UI Tabbar Click programmatically / with Shortcut

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am using material UIs tabs in my electron/ react application like so:

```
        <Tabs>
          <Tab label="View1" >
            <View1 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab
            label="View2">
            <View2 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab label="View3" >
            <View3 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab label="View4" >
            <View4 />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
```

I now want to press a shortcut, and in doing so, change the view. So, for example, say Tab1 is active and View1 is rendered. I then press `Cmd + 2` and then Tab2 will opened (with View2 being active), in exactly the same way as if I had clicked on Tab2. How would I do this? I have tried a few things, and I would have an idea how to do this without material UI, but I am confused by the material UI syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send 1 prop to `Tabs` to control what tab opens:

```
    <Tabs value={this.state.tabIndex}>
      <Tab label="View1" >
        <View1 />
      </Tab>
      <Tab
        label="View2">
        <View2 />
      </Tab>
      <Tab label="View3" >
        <View3 />
      </Tab>
      <Tab label="View4" >
        <View4 />
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
```

Then add a method to change its value:

```
changeTab = (tabIndex) => {
  this.setState({ tabIndex })
}
```

Comment: The value property on the tab is also needed to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should define handler-method for handling keyboard event and update state if was pressed appropriate keys combination.  Look at this working example - https://jsfiddle.net/2m8ho95r/1/ (Note: you should click in result area on jsfiddle page before shortcut pressing):

Here tabs will change after `Ctrl/Cmd + 1` and `Ctrl/Cmd + 2`. If you need only `Cmd` - remove `|| event.ctrlKey`:

```
class TabsExampleControlled extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'a',
    };

    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  handleKeyPress(event) {
    if ((event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) && event.keyCode === 49) { // CTRL+1 or CMD+1
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ value: 'a' });
    }

    if ((event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) && event.keyCode === 50) { // CTRL+2 or CMD+2
    event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ value: 'b' });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs
        value={this.state.value}
      >
        <Tab label="Tab A" value="a">
          <div>
            <h2 style={styles.headline}>Controllable Tab A</h2>
            <p>
              Tabs are also controllable if you want to programmatically pass them their values.
              This allows for more functionality in Tabs such as not
              having any Tab selected or assigning them different values.
            </p>
          </div>
        </Tab>
        <Tab label="Tab B" value="b">
          <div>
            <h2 style={styles.headline}>Controllable Tab B</h2>
            <p>
              This is another example of a controllable tab. Remember, if you
              use controllable Tabs, you need to give all of your tabs values or else
              you wont be able to select them.
            </p>
          </div>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs, Tabs property section contains the explanation on the value property -

> Makes Tabs controllable and selects the tab whose value prop matches this prop.

The above in explained in the Code snippet -

```
// ...inside a component
state = {
    selectedTab: "tab1" // by default, tab1 to be selected.
};

handleTabChange = (tabValue) => {
    this.setState({selectedTab: tabValue});
};

// Inside render()
<Tabs value={this.state.selectedTab} onChange={this.handleTabChange}>
    <Tab label="Tab 1" value="tab1">
        <div>...</div>
    </Tab>
    <Tab label="Tab 2" value="tab2">
        <div>...</div>
    </Tab>
<Tabs>
```

With the above wiring in place, setState({selectedTab: ""}) can be used to programmatically select the desired tab.